# Extracting image attachments from geodatabase with image names according to attributes in certain field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase, attachments

I have data from the field survey using Survey123 for ArcGIS in the geodatabase format. I want to extract all attachments from the geodatabase. I want the name of the image in the extraction to follow the name of the attribute in the "Nama Rupabumi" field as you can see in the following attachment.

[Data Survey](https://flic.kr/p/2fm6YYp)

I had tried this script from ESRI Support

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import da
import os

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID']) as cursor:
for item in cursor:
    attachment = item[0]
    filenum = "ATT" + str(item[2]) + "_"
    filename = filenum + str(item[1])
    open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
    del item
    del filenum
    del filename
    del attachment
```

but the image name is not what I want

I don't understand coding like in the python above.

Comment: It appears you have grabbed the code from [here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011912), the blue box explains which table is the input. You need to look inside your geodatabase and study the attachment table to see where the values are coming from.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I took the python code from that link. I learned from the python code that the name of the extracted image uses the name from  "surveyPoint__ATTACH" table, [link](https://flic.kr/p/2efBaRL). 

What I want to do, the name of extracted image is taken from atribut of "Nama Rupabumi" field in "surveyPoint" table, [link](https://flic.kr/p/2fmwfWD).

Comment: I think you need to get the global ID in  _ATTACH table and then match that with global ID in point featureclass, that's a simple search cursor, then you will be able to extract the name and build a file name based on that.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I modified the above script to include the GlobalID in the file name to relate the photo to the feature resulting in a filename like "ATT1_{75D79B22-BCDA-4672-A682-691237295156}_Photo 1.jpg". Could you elaborate on how to then use search cursor in python to extract the related feature name and attach to the exported attachment filename?

Comment: Not here you need to post a question, say what you have done and why it is not working?